# jQuery addClass-like functionality on a different attribute

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I wonder if there's a more general function in jQuery that works like addClass() but on something different from the dom className attribute.

I have a data field which stores labels of validation rules, something like this:

```
<input data-validation="required number positive">,
```

each label specifying a different type of validation. I would like to be able to modify validation labels like this:

```
$('input').addToken('data-validation', 'date future_date'); // two rules added here
```

or

```
$('input').removeToken('data-validation', 'required');
```

My best solution so far would be to take $.fn._addClass and copy it into a new function, however, I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel if possible.

In a similar direction, as far as I know, CSS2 has a special attribute selector that works on this kind of space-separated values, on any attribute, not just className:

> E[foo~="warning"] Matches any E element whose "foo" attribute value is
>   a list of space-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to
>   "warning".

PS. Maybe someone with a higher reputation than mine could add the tag 'space-separated-values', I think it could be a useful tag. Thank you.

Comment: is `$('input').data('validation','date future_date')` not working out for ya?

Comment: Well, there is no such function available in JS or jQuery, so you have to write your own. It's just a little bit of string manipulation anyway

Comment: You will have to create a jQuery plugin(s) with .addToken() & .removeToken() method(s) if you want that syntax. Other than that you have $('input').attr('data-validation', 'required'); and $('input').data('validation'); and you don't even have to write code to implement it - it comes standard!

Comment: ok, what I want is not to SET a value to the attribute overwriting the previous value, but to append a word (token) to that value, or remove a token. Much like addClass and removeClass work with the className attribute.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provide a `data()` function that enabled you access to all `data-*` defined on an element, So you can do:

```
//set value
$('input').data('validation','date future_date');

//get values
var validations = $('input').data('validation');
```